# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers

When I'm trying to compile this code with gcc version 4.6.3 on linux with `-Wall` flag I'm getting these two warnings:

1. It points to `cmd[1]=cmd2send;`

   > warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
2. It points to the variable `static unsigned char *cmd[65]`

   > warning: variable ‘cmd’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable].

*What makes these warnings? and how to avoid them?*

```
  int CommandHandler(unsigned char cmd2send)
    {
        static unsigned char *cmd[65];

        // *make sure device is open*
        if(handle==NULL) // handle defined in transceiver.h
        {
            puts("CommandHandler::Cant handle command");
            // try to open device again
            if(OpenMyDev()!=0)
            return -1;
            // if no return then retry is fine
            puts("retry SUCCEEDED!, device is open");
        }

        // *send command to firmware*
        cmd[0]=0x0;
        cmd[1]=cmd2send;
        .......
        return 0;

    }
```

Here, also I'm getting warning #2 for variable voltage:

```
float Get_Temperature(void)
{
    //unsigned char RecvByte=0;
    //int byte[4];

    int i;

    float voltage=0;
    float resistance=0;
    float temperature=0;
    float SamplesAVG=0;

    unsigned int Samples=0;

    unsigned char* rvc;
    unsigned char mydata[65];


    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        //Transimit Start Of Frame
        mydata[0]=0;
        mydata[1]=GET_TEMPERATURE;

        if(Write2MyDev(mydata)<0)  {return -1;}

        rvc=ReadMyDev(0);

        SamplesAVG+=(rvc[0]<<24)+(rvc[1]<<16)+(rvc[2]<<8)+rvc[3];
        usleep(100*1000);
    }

    Samples=SamplesAVG/10;
    printf("TO PRINT VAL:%d\n",Samples);
    puts("------------");

    voltage = (Samples * 5.0)/1023.0; // 0..1203= 1024 values
    resistance = 10000.0/ (1023.0/Samples);
    ...
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: well.. what do you really want to do?

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't add a cast!** The text of the warning is a little misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd2send` is an `unsigned char` and you are setting the value at `cmd[1]` which is a `char *` to it. A `char *` is a pointer and an `unsigned char` is treated like an integer so you are making a pointer `cmd[1]` from an `integer` without a cast.

Chances are you wanted an array of characters `char cmd[65]` not an array of `char *`

Also since you created and assigned values to `cmd` but you never use it you get a warning for that as well.

Comment: please check the second code sample

Comment: @MaxwellS. He answers that as well.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> static unsigned char *cmd[65];
> ....
> cmd[1] = cmd2send; /* cmd is an array of pointers so cmd[1] is a pointer. */
> ```

Okay, so `cmd` is an array pf 256 pointers. Assigning a `char` to `cmd[1]` generates the first warning.

The compiler also notices **you're not actually using `cmd`** anywhere so it generates the second warning.

Comment: please check the second code sample

Comment: @MaxwellS. You can't keep milking this thread. Show that you learned something.

Comment: thank you for your effort, the point is, im here for solve my code warnings, and if i've learned something i will not hesitate to show it.